# No Office XP Updates since installed Compatibility Pack from WSUS

Tags: windows-xp, wsus, microsoft-office

we got a bunch of boxes, running Windows XP and Office XP. Since we installed the Office 2007 Compatibility Pack, Office XP does not get updates anymore.
Our WSUS provides Office 2007 patches for these computers but no Office XP, e.g. the urgantly needed Serice Pack 3.

We allready tried to remove the Compatibility Pack and Office XP, reinstalled Office but there was no change.

Do you have any hints?

PS: The Office XP has been installed from a compressed ISO, so no administrative installation point.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is ensure WSUS is actually getting the updates.

Assuming WSUS 3.X:

Check that Office XP updates are requested:  Options--> Products and Classifications, ensure "Office 2002/XP" is check-marked.

Check to see what Office XP patches WSUS knows about:  Updates--> All Updates, Search--> enter "Office XP" in the "text" search box.

You should have quite a few listed.

If that all lines up, then perhaps as the next troubleshooting test go back to one of the client machines and manually hit www.microsoftupdate.com and see what it offers for Office, as that may give some hints as to why the updates are not making it to the client(s).

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The WSUS gets all the Office updates we need. The Windows Update / Microsoft Update Site does not work due to a group policy, but I do know that at least the service pack 3 is missing and should be installed.
According to the WSUS Management Console, it's in there and installed for some machines, needed for some other and not appliable to all the computers, equipped with the Compatibility Pack.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at **[this](https://serverfault.com/questions/3901/force-install-updates-on-wsus-server)** question and try to install the update manually.  If that doesn't work, then it might be a bug with MSFT and worth reporting/opening a ticket with MSFT.

Comment: We already built a script, deleting the SoftwareDistribution Folder and resetting the WSUS cookies - did not work.